# For loop doesn't end using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop

I have this simple code:

File `app.js`:

```
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');

var downloader = require('./routers/downloader.js');

const app = express();

downloadAll();

function downloadAll() {
    downloader.test();
}
```

File `downloader.js`:

```
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');
var methods = {};

methods.test = function(req, res) {
    for(var i = 1; 10; i++) {
        console.log(i); // DOESN'T WORK
    }

    var obj;
    fs.readFile('./output/ita-2015-24m.json', 'utf8', function(err, data) {
        if(err) {
            throw err;
        }
        obj = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(obj); 
    }
}

module.exports = methods;
```

When I run `app.js` using `node app.js`, I get: `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, ...`.
The loop doesn't end.

I try to change position to this loop, interting it inside `readFile` function but it's the same problem.

My goal is iterate throug `obj` object.

Why? How can I solve?

Comment: Your `var methods = {};` is a variable that hold the value of an empty `object`. You should use a `for in` loop (watch out for non-enumerable properties) instead of testing your code with a for loop

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> When I run app.js using node app.js, I get: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,
>   10, 11, 12, .... The loop doesn't end.

Your loop doesn't have **end-condition**, hence it will keep on incrementing `i`

Make it

```
for(var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    console.log(i); // DOESN'T WORK
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've written 
`for(var i = 1; 10; i++)`

The loop will never end because 10 is always true (or at least never false).  Should be something like:

`for(var i = 1; i<10; i++)`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
for(var i = 1; 10; i++)
```

Try:

```
for(var i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want 10 elements you can use

```
for(var i = 1; i<= 10; i++)
```

or

```
for(var i = 0; i< 10; i++)
```